# Map three different functions to Observable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, reactive-programming, rxjs

I am new to Rxjs. I want to follow best practices if possible.

I am trying to perform three distinct functions on the same data that is returned in an observable. Following the 'streams of data' concept, I keep on thinking I need to split this Observable into three streams and carry on.

Here is my code, so I can stop talking abstractly:

```
// NotEmptyResponse splits the stream in 2 to account based on whether I get an empty observable back.  
let base_subscription = RxNode.fromStream(siteStream).partition(NotEmptyResponse);

// Success Stream to perform further actions upon. 
let successStream = base_subscription[0];

// The Empty stream for error reporting
let failureStream = base_subscription[1];

//Code works up until this point. I don't know how to split to 3 different streams. 
successStream.filter(isSite)
             .map(grabData)// Async action that returns data
             /*** Perform 3 separate actions upon data that .map(grabData) returned **/ 
             .subscribe();
```

How can I split this data stream into three, and map each instance of the data to a different function?

Comment: What do you mean by _"map each instance of the data to a different function"_? You want to split `siteStream` into three Observables instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact `partition()` operator internally just [calls `filter()` operator twice](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/partition.js.html#lineNumber44). First to create an Observable from values matching the `predicate` and then for values not matching the `predicate`.

So you can do the exact same thing with [filter() operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter):

```
let obs1 = base_subscription.filter(val => predicate1);
let obs2 = base_subscription.filter(val => predicate2);
let obs3 = base_subscription.filter(val => predicate3);
```

Now you have three Observables, each of them emitting only some specific values. Then you can carry on with your existing code:

```
obs2.filter(isSite)
    .map(grabData)
    .subscribe();
```

Just be aware that calling `subscribe()` triggers the generating values from the source Observable. This doesn't have to be always like this depending on what Observable you use. See [“Hot” and “Cold” Observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) in the documentation. [Operator `connect()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html) might be useful for you depending on your usecase.

Comment: I was slowly figuring this out last night, ,but you confirmed my suspicions. I will check out connect operator. Appreciate the help.